# ortp/ortp.h not found in LinPhone LIbrary

Tags: xcode, linphone

I am trying to complie linphone.xcodeProj downloaded from github.But it throws the error ortp/ortp.h not found .How can i solve this error.Please help me

Comment: Do you have the oRTP library?  (I haven't used this but if you don't have it try following: http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/ortp/downloads)

Comment: same problem I have facing any solution.?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build Setting and in header search path add the following line

```
"$(SRCROOT)/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/include"
```

Comment: Already this file present in header search ,any other solution to add that file