# How could we implement Voice calling functionality by using WiFi/3G Internet in iOS?

Tags: linphone, xcode6.4, ios8.4

I want to implement voice calling functionality by using *WiFi/3G* *Internet*,I am tired implementing it by using.

**1)*LinPhone Library***

Download source code from:
  https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone
When I run Linphone code it shows me error message:

> 'ortp/ortp.h' file not found

But in Library, file is present *ortp.h*.
For solution I used [ortp/ortp.h not found in LinPhone LIbrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236756/ortp-ortp-h-not-found-in-linphone-library) and did changes which is mention in solution, but error not solved. How to fix that error issue?

Is there another **Free Library** for Voice calling? How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

i think u didnt read "readme" file. follow it . you will get the answer .first confirm which resolution you are using it . 64 bit or 32 bit. did you check library search path under build setting

Comment: yes I check 32bit resource ,Could you explain detail answer,

Answer (score 0):

you cant able to send 32 bit bit app to itunesconnect .so  download 64 now . [link] (https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone). [enter link description here][1]once you downloaded follow the steps given the same page .invoke the sdk by using homebrew. once you done these, add add these lines in library and header search paths under build setting [![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: I am download latest sdk https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone, it work on  ios 6.0 ,when I set target 8.4 it show me error message , could you please tell me  Linphone only support ios6.0..?

Comment: show me the error.. i am also using the same sdk and same target .. i found errors at first . but guidance given in the page helped me .. now it is working fine .

Comment: Could you please send me your mail id,I will share you screenshots,Can it support iOS 8.4 n above..?

Comment: please send your mail id .. i ll connect you there... if it is urgent , say it .. i ll send you a demo project ... doing by yourself ll get you d complete process .